# How to compute PID cpu load?

Tags: bash, 64-bit, cpu-load, jboss

Please help me to find a reliable way to compute (in a bash script) a jboss PID cpu load.

To be specific, I don't know how to aggregate `/proc/[pid]/stat` fields to obtain the load a specific process makes on a multiple cpu 64 bit env. Ubuntu.

Thanks a lot,
Xander

Answer (score 2):

The tool that interprets the `/proc/[pid]/stat` information is `ps`, this tools allows you to get the cpu load of any single process on the system:

```
ps S -p [pid] -o pcpu=
```

To monitor using this command, you can use watch:

```
watch ps S -p [pid] -o pcpu=
```

This command outputs a percentage of total cpu use of the agregate of all child processes. If you want to see the tree of processes, use pstree:

```
pstree -p [pid]
```

Comment: actually I belive "ps -Lp(pid) opcpu" does aggregate all pid's threads, isn't it? Unfortunately ps gives just snapshots of that cpu/thread load (it can't be used in real-time monitoring), and aggregating in the bash script all 300 threads in a jboss, by "cat"-ing all the file specific for that child pids it looks kind of unreliable.

Comment: @xander - See my updates for further clarification.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I used the ps application and compared with `top -d 1 -p [pid]` output. While top updates the load, (like 30% 33% 37% 31%) ps returns a static percent (like 33% 33% 33% 33% etc...), just like a snapshot. Any solution?

Comment: What happens if you run ps in one window and top in another?